# Remove onClickListener from ImageView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `LinearLayout` with adding some images dynamically with their click listeners.
When I'm clicking on an `ImageView` I want to remove `Onclick` listener from all the `ImageViews` to prevent clicking on any `ImageView` again.

Can anyone suggest any permanent idea without `boolean` variable.

Comment: post some code atleast

Answer (score 3):

Set the onClickListener to null:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could give your `LinearLayout` an id, and then loop over all children and set the listener to null;

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.imagesLayout);
View v = null;

for(int i=0; i<layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if(v instanceOf ImageView) //you dont have to do this when there are only imageViews
        v.setOnClickListener(null)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(null);
```

or

```
imageView.setClickable(false);
```